# If $A^2+A=0$, is A invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, inverse

As the title states, if $A^2+A=0$, is it possible to determine whether A is invertible?

This's how I'm thinking. Factoring we get:

$A(A+I)=0$

Hence, either $A=0$ or $A=-I$

We know that $A = 0$ certainly isn't invertible, so it must be the case that $A=-I$ is our matrix, and since $-I$ is invertible, then A itself must be invertible.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you name $A_1$ and $A_2$? are they not the same matrix?

Comment: $AB=0$ does not imply $A=0$ or $B=0$.

Comment: "A(A+I)=0 then A=0  or A=−I", why? This is true for fields but not for arbitrary rings

Comment: @Lab That's true, I didn't think of it like that.

Comment: @Owen Yes, they're. I'll edit my post.

Comment: The statement [$A^2+A=0\implies A\text{ invertible}$] is false, and in $A=0$ we have a counterexample.

Comment: @GauravChandan Oh okay. If I've understood it correctly, the implication doesn't work the other way around. So that's why I cant make that conclusion?

Comment: @drhab Thank you, that was a good way of explaining it.

Comment: Consider $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Tanamas, to be more precise,you can't conclusively determine $A$'s invertibility without knowing it's actual value because $A=-I$ is the only possibility wherein  $A$ is invertible AND the equation in the title holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A being invertible implies that $A=−I$, so if $A≠−I$, it's non-invertible (note that this is the contrapositive of the first implication). So, you can't say for sure if $A$ is invertible or not unless you know what A is. But you can say that $A$ is invertible and the equation in the title holds iff $A=−I$.

($A$ is invertible $\land$ $A^2 + A = 0$) $\iff A = -I$

The forward implication is proven above and the reverse implication can be proven by assigning $A:=-I$.

Comment: I've made the necessary edit now. Thanks for the suggestion @Joe

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your initial question is "no", a counterexample is given by $A = 0$, but for example also by $$A = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

The problem with your reasoning is the step "$A ( A + I) = 0 \implies A = 0$ or $A + I = 0$". The ring of square matrices of size at least $2\times 2$ has zero divisors, so that conclusion is wrong in general (again, consider the above $2\times 2$ counterexample).